# Asignación a una variable definida como puntero

Tags: c

El siguiente código me genera "segmentation fault" y no entiendo por qué:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *a;

  *a=1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el puntero `a` apunta a un espacio  de memoria invalida o no asignado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es causado porque puntero `a` apunta a un espacio de memoria invalida o no asignado.

En tu caso funcionaria si haces lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int *a, b;
  a = &b; /*asignar la dirección de memoria de a a b*/
  *a = 199; /* asignar a `a` un valor usando el puntero */

  printf("el valor de a es %d", a);

  return 0;
}
```

O por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *a;
  a=malloc(sizeof(int));

  *a=1;
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Trauma estoy buscando más sustento, pero una respuesta corta no implica baja calidad.

Comment: OOH! Es cierto, añadiendo esto: a=malloc(sizeof(int)*1); se soluciona.

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. Si te sirvió la respuesta, recuerda que puedes (y es lo correcto) marcarla como `aceptada`, pulsando el símbolo del *check* a la izquierda (debajo de las flechas de votos)

Comment: ¿Y por qué se puede asignar la dirección sin especificar el valor de "b"? (en el primer código)

Comment: b inicialmente puede tener un valor cualquiera o cero en compiladores modernos, pero si tiene un espacio de memoria asignado, en cambio el puntero tiene espacio de memoria para guardar una direccion, pero el valor de esa direccion no esta definida asi que podria apuntar a cualquier lado.

Comment: Oook creo que lo entiendo; entonces modificar *a es lo mismo que modificar b (en ese caso)

Comment: Exacto, *a referencia a la variable b.